# Add custom lines to geom_violin in ggplot / ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I have thresholds for each of the groups of my data, and when plotting a violin plot I would like these to be shown within the plots.

Instead, the lines are not constrained to the corresponding groups and the lines are only shown either full width (ggplot), or a small section of the whole plot (ggplotly).

I think that `stat_sina` from the `ggforce` package is the way forward, however I am having no luck.

My code is:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

customLines <- data.frame(name = c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width'),
                          value = c(2, 1, 5, 3))

iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name,
             y = value,
             fill = name,
             colour = name,
             group = name)) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.3) +
  ggforce::geom_sina() +
  ggforce::stat_sina(data = customLines,
                     aes(x = name,
                         yintercept = value),
                     geom = "hline")
ggplotly()
```

Which outputs

[image]

As is clear to see, this doesn't correspond with the violin plots.

How can I have the lines only go the full width of the violin plots, and within the violins? It might be similar to the quantile approach, but I have no clue how to use this in this format either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution uses `ggplot_build` to identify the correct width of the violin plot, then use that information in `geom_segment`. `ggplotly` also works with my solution (figure not shown).

```r
library(tidyverse)
customLines <- data.frame(name = c('Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Sepal.Length', 'Sepal.Width'),
                          value = c(2, 1, 5, 3))

customLines <- customLines %>% 
  mutate(fac = as.integer(factor(name, levels = name)))

p1 <- iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name,
             y = value,
             fill = name,
             colour = name,
             group = name)) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.3)

violin_width <- ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]] %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarize(width = max(violinwidth)) %>% 
  left_join(customLines, by = c("x" = "fac"))

p1 + 
  geom_segment(data = violin_width, 
               aes(x = x - width/2, y = value, xend = x + width/2, yend = value))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-05-12 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Clever! You can actually get the exact violin width (rather than the max) with something like `violin_width <- ggplot_build(p1)$data[[1]] %>% select(y, x, violinwidth) %>% left_join(customLines %>% mutate(x = as.integer(factor(name, levels = name)))) %>% group_by(x) %>% filter(y >= value) %>% slice(1)`

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thank you for the alternative solution! May I ask why is `filter(y >= value)` necessary? I'm just thinking if the max width happens at `y < value`, then filtering might actually do harm. Or did I misunderstood something? Thank you again!

Comment: The `y` values don't correspond with `values` across the two dataframes, so the filter finds the `ggplot_build` y's that exceed the OP's `values` and then the `slice` selects the first one (i.e the first one to just exceed `value`). It is just a form of fuzzy join.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite what you want, but you could use `geom_tile` to plot a line (a very short tile) like this. ..

```
iris %>%
  pivot_longer(-Species) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = name,
             y = value,
             fill = name,
             colour = name,
             group = name)) +
  geom_violin(alpha = 0.3) +
  geom_tile(data = customLines,
            aes(x = name,
                y = value),
            height = 0.01,
            width = 0.5)
```

[image]